# Problem with $post_id object's property

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, columns

Dealing with retrieving CPT metadata I find out two methods `get_post_meta()` and `get_post_custom()` to return the value(s) of the custom fields with the specified key from the specified post. Both methods are passing the `$post_id` as first parameter to access global `$post` object's ID property.

Now my question is, how does WordPress figure out which CPT or POST we are asking for? For example at following example how does WordPress understand which post we are talking about

```
function save_options(){
  global $post;
  if (!isset($_POST['price']) || $post->post_type != 'product')
  {
    return $post;
  }
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $_POST['price']);
```

Comment: I am not following your question. If method accepts unique numerical ID for a post, that is precisely how it knows that is post to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider this question to be borderline unanswerable. It really depends on context.

In your example `$post` is whatever that `global` has been set to. That is pretty general, pretty obvious, and not really saying much but without knowing the context in which this code executes it is hard to give a better answer.

That variable is set for each post in the Loop by `setup_postdata` or `the_post` and it is set on some back-end pages in similar ways, based ultimately in `$_GET` or `$_POST` data whether that `$_GET` or `$_POST` data contains a post ID or components of a query.

Many of the hooks and filters that you use are passed that value so it is not always necessary to grab the global directly.